# Magento 2 - Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

I want to create a cart price rule in such a manner that

i have 2 products SKU-1, SKU-2

when customer contains above two products in cart and applied that coupon the discount will be £1. and also i would like add further discount if the customer increse the quantity of two products like below,

1 x SKU-1 & 1 x SKU-2. Discount = £1.00

2 x SKU-1 & 2 x SKU-2. Discount = £2.00

3 x SKU-1 & 3 x SKU-2. Discount = £3.00

and so on...

How can i achieve this cart price rule.